# How to give tabindex in check_box_tag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tabindex

I have includded given code

```
<%= check_box_tag :is_license_accepted, :value => true, :tabindex => '1' %>
```

but its not working please guide me how to give tabindex with checkbox in rails

Comment: Try `<%= check_box_tag :is_license_accepted, true, false, :tabindex => '1' %>`. As per the [syntax](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag), the third option check whether checkbox should be checked or not

Answer (score 0):

`check_box_tag` accepts up to 4 arguments:

1. the name of the tag
2. the value (defaults to '1')
3. the checked status (defaults to false)
4. a hash of additional options (defaults to {})

If you want to pass `tabindex` in the options hash, you need to explicitly pass the previous 3 arguments:

```
<%= check_box_tag :is_license_accepted, true, false, :tabindex => '1' %>
```

Here is [the method's documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag), for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `check_box_tag` to this:

```
<%= check_box_tag :is_license_accepted, true, false, :tabindex => '1' %>
```

See the [documentation here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag).

For you, it's not currently working because it expects a `value` param in the 2nd argument of `check_box_tag` but you are sending a hash instead: `:value => true`. So, you need to change that to only the value without the key which is:`true` NOT `:value => true`.

Another issue with your current code is, you don't have the 3rd argument present. Default value for the 3rd argument for `check_box_tag` is `false` so you can send that to the 3rd argument.

The 4th argument is a `options hash` where you can send any extra parameter and here you can send the `:tablindex => 1` hash which you already did.